# Why Ubuntu and openSUSE's GNU C program linker produce different mapfile?

Tags: ld, opensuse

In brief, I find that running gcc on openSUSE does not produce a map file that shows me **"As-needed library included to satisfy reference by file (symbol)"** paragraph. I'm wondering why.

Lab environments:

- Ubuntu 18.04, gcc 7.5.0, binutils 2.30 (2019-05-08)
- openSUSE Leap 15.5, gcc 7.5.0, binutils 2.39 (2022-10-25)

A simple `foo1.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void FooX(int);

void Foo1(int i)
{
        printf("foo1(%d)\n", i);
        i++;
        FooX(i);
}
```

The compile command is:

```
gcc foo1.c -fpic -shared -o libfoo1.so -Wl,-Map=foo1.map,--cref
```

This produces `libfoo1.so` and `foo1.map` .

On Ubuntu, I see at start of the mapfile:

> ```
> As-needed library included to satisfy reference by file (symbol)
>
> libc.so.6                     /tmp/cch6AxRm.o (printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5)
> ```
>
> [image: Ubuntu mapfile]

It says that `libc.so.6` is needed by my `libfoo1.so`, due to the latter needs `printf` symbol from the former.

However, doing the same on openSUSE 15.5 gives me different `foo1.map` which does NOT have the "As-needed library included to satisfy reference by file" information.

[image: openSUSE mapfile]

ChatGPT suggests that I add linker option `--as-needed` to openSUSE's gcc. I tried it, no effect.

I'm really curious, what makes the difference on the two Linux distros, or, can I force openSUSE to produce the as-needed info for me?